# Submit button placement on a form with long columns

Tags: forms, checkboxes, scrolling, submit

This question is related to the [Sticky submit button at the top and bottom of the form?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/91067/sticky-submit-button-at-top-and-bottom-of-the-form), and [Submit button on top of the long form](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24737/submit-button-on-top-of-the-long-form) but I consider has other nuances.

I have a form that is made only with checkboxes. They don't need to be all checked. I have some javascript to handle possible errors.

This is what can be seen on a standard monitor:

[image]

And this is the complete form:

[image]

At the top of each column, I have a button that allows the user to check or uncheck all, so the user can just uncheck all items and send the form without the need to scroll down to the bottom.

I thought the most convenient solution would be to place the submit button at the top of the form so as not to confuse the user if they don't need to scroll to the end.

Is this a reasonable approach? Are there any reasons why it wouldn't be?

Comment: If you know the form is always going to be long, why not just have a submit button at the top ***and*** bottom?

Comment: @musefan Opinions seem a little divided on the matter, take this comment for example in one of the links I mention: *Two buttons that are shown at the same time? One at the top and one at the bottom? Why? If you have two buttons showing at once, the user might wonder why there are two and could confuse someone*. But it's true that in the case of my form is too long, the buttons won't appear at the same time in the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this situation very often and the regular approach is a `checkbox button` beside the title with two actions:

- Select all the items below this title
- Unselect all the items below this title

and one info state:

- This title has some selected items

[image]

[image]

About the submit button at the bottom usually has the functionality that forces the user to read all the content. If this is not necessary, the best option in my opinion is the button to the right of the titles.

---

This screenshot is from the **FontExplorer** font selector where is possible to select/unselect all the fonts in a set, or just some of those included in it:

[image]